# how to get length of audio file in codeigniter while upload file

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have an issue related file upload, 
I want to get the audio file's duration length in minutes. 
While I am uploading that file, I am able to get all the details like size, type, max-length, file name but not the duration of that audio file.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/songs/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|mov|mp3|aiff|mpeg|zip';
$config['max_size'] = '30000';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '1024';
$config['file_ext_tolower'] = 'TRUE';
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$uploadSong = $this->upload->data();
print_r($uploadSong);
```

after print_r am getting this output of uploaded file

```
Array ( 
  [file_name] => song_one1.mp3 
  [file_type] => application/octet-stream 
  [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/rockherogame/uploads/songs/         
  [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/rockherogame/uploads/songs/song_one1.mp3 
  [raw_name] => song_one1 
  [orig_name] => song_one.mp3 
  [client_name] => song_one.mp3 
  [file_ext] => .mp3 
  [file_size] => 4059.28 
  [is_image] => 
  [image_width] => 
  [image_height] => 
  [image_type] => 
  [image_size_str] => )
```

please help me understand how to get duration of file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how to use this in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Duration of a audio file needs to be calculated.

here is a good example showing how to do the same in php

http://www.zedwood.com/article/127/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3

you can also Install and use `getid3`.
code snippet [here](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source/?p=demo.simple.write.phps)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, notice the getduration function: http://www.zedwood.com/article/127/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3